# XML Deserialization to nested array of objects

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm getting some XML from a web service. I build some classes to deserialize it to. It's partially working; I get expected values for the primitive members of any `SavingType` objects.

As the code is, I get a single `Saving` object where there ought to be multiple, and its fields are null. I have some commented attributes on the `Savings` member (maybe I ought to change these names). Those attributes seem like the ought to be more correct than the uncommented `XmlElement` I have on there, but the `Savings` member of the deserialized object is always an empty array when I use them. Where's my mistake(s)?

```
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
    <AdvSaving>
        <SavingType>...</SavingType>
        <SavingType>...</SavingType>
        <SavingType>
            <Savings>
                <Saving>
                    <apy>0.06</apy>
                    <dailyBalance>0.01</dailyBalance>
                    <divRate>0.06</divRate>
                    <name>Ultimate Checking </name>
                </Saving>
                <Saving>
                    <apy>0.10</apy>
                    <dailyBalance>10,000.00</dailyBalance>
                    <divRate>0.10</divRate>
                    <name>Ultimate Checking</name>
                </Saving>
                <Saving>
                    <apy>0.06</apy>
                    <dailyBalance>0.01</dailyBalance>
                    <divRate>0.06</divRate>
                    <name>Business Rewards Checking</name>
                </Saving>
            </Savings>
            <savingNote>All rates are subject to change without prior notification.  The APY figure assumes the principal and earned dividends remain on deposit until maturity.  Fees may reduce earnings.&#xD;
 &#xD;
1 Must meet age requirements to participate.</savingNote>
            <savingsMinBal>Minimum to open is $0.00</savingsMinBal>
            <savingsTypeName>Checking</savingsTypeName>
        </SavingType>
    </AdvSaving>
    <effectiveDate>Rates effective from 11/01/2018 through 11/30/2018</effectiveDate>
</Product>
```

And the classes:

```
namespace InitechServiceEntities
{
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Product
    {
        //...
        [XmlArrayItem("SavingType", typeof(SavingType), IsNullable = false)]
        public SavingType[] AdvSaving;
        [XmlElement("effectiveDate")]
        public string effectiveDate;
    }

    [XmlType("SavingType")]
    public class SavingType
    {
        [XmlElement("savingsTypeName")]
        public string savingsTypeName;
        [XmlElement("savingsMinBal")]
        public string savingsMinBal;
        [XmlElement("savingNote")]
        public string savingNote;
        [XmlElement("Savings")]
        //[XmlArray(ElementName = "Savings")]
        //[XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Saving))]
        public Saving[] Savings;
    }

    [XmlType("Saving")]
    public class Saving
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string name;
        [XmlElement("dailyBalance")]
        public decimal dailyBalance;
        [XmlElement("divRate")]
        public decimal divRate;
        [XmlElement("apy")]
        public decimal apy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your data model:

1. In `SavingType`, the `Savings` array must be marked with [`[XmlArray("Savings")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) to indicate that the collection is serialized with an outer container element `<Savings>` and inner elements `<Saving>`:

   ```
   // FIXED
   [XmlArray("Savings")]
   public Saving[] Savings;
   ```

   You had originally marked the array in that manner, then commented it out and replaced it with [`[XmlArray(ElementName = "Savings")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) which indicates the collection should be serialized without the outer element -- which does not reflect the actual XML.
2. Having fixed #1, you will encounter a second problem, namely that the value `10,000.00` for `<dailyBalance>10,000.00</dailyBalance>` cannot be parsed as a [decimal](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal) due to the presence of a comma, and so an exception gets thrown during deserialization.

   To solve this you will need to change `Saving.dailyBalance` to a `string`, or introduce a surrogate property that does the parsing manually:

   ```
   // FIXED
   [XmlElement("dailyBalance")]
   public string dailyBalance;
   ```

Thus the modified fixed types would look like:

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/mInitechService", IsNullable = false)]
public class Product
{
    [XmlArrayItem("SavingType", typeof(SavingType), IsNullable = false)]
    public SavingType[] AdvSaving;
    [XmlElement("effectiveDate")]
    public string effectiveDate;
}

[XmlType("SavingType")]
public class SavingType
{
    [XmlElement("savingsTypeName")]
    public string savingsTypeName;
    [XmlElement("savingsMinBal")]
    public string savingsMinBal;
    [XmlElement("savingNote")]
    public string savingNote;

    // FIXED
    //[XmlElement("Savings")]
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Savings")]
    public Saving[] Savings;
}

[XmlType("Saving")]
public class Saving
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name;

    // FIXED
    [XmlElement("dailyBalance")]
    public string dailyBalance;

    [XmlElement("divRate")]
    public decimal divRate;
    [XmlElement("apy")]
    public decimal apy;
}
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CzZHaY).

As an aside, such problems are often easy to diagnose by constructing an instance of your model in memory, then serializing to XML.  When you compare the generated XML with the XML you want to deserialize, any differences in structure will indicate where you deserialization code has bugs.

Comment: I was just looking at `dailyBalance` when I saw your post. Thanks for the help!